# asp.net change menu text after validation

Tags: c#, asp.net

how would i change the menu taskbar after validation. i currently have a link box and a label

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // check if user is logged in
        if (Session["login"] != null)
        {
            LblLogin.Text = "Welcome " + Session["Login"].ToString();
            LblLogin.Visible = true;
            LinkButton1.Text = "Logout";
        }
        else
        {
            LblLogin.Visible = false;
            LinkButton1.Text = "Login";
        }
    }

    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //user logs in
        if (LinkButton1.Text == "Login")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Manage_Register.aspx?Scr=");
        }
        else
        {
            //User logs out
            Session.Clear();
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?Scr=");
        }
```

however i now want it on the menu , on the menu bar i have `home, about, contact, login`
when a user successfully logs in i want the login text to change to logout.

Comment: You can use the login controls provided, specifically:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.ASPX#the_loginview_control

Comment: @luke2012 what i created is almost the same as 'login controls' but i want it on the menu-bar, also the login control is the linkbox way

Comment: @user2158735 can you show ASPX markup for your menu?